# Prove that, if $d$ is a metric, then $\frac{d}{1+d}$ is equivalent to $d$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, then $d' = \frac{d}{1+d}$ and $d$ are equivalent; furthermore let $B_\theta(x, \epsilon) = \{y \in X\ |\ \theta(x,y) < \epsilon\}$ for some metric $\theta$ over $X$. I wanna ask you guys if my proof is correct.

**Edit 1:**
The question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309198/if-dx-y-is-a-metric-then-fracdx-y1-dx-y-is-also-a-metric) ask if, given a metric $d$, $d' = \frac{d}{1+d}$ is also a metric; my question is different as by hypothesis I already know that $d$ and $d'$ are metrics, so given that I'm asking if my below proof, showing that $d$ and $d'$ are equivalent metrics, is correct.

**Proof:**
Since $d' = \frac{d}{1+d} \le d, \ \forall x,y \in X$, then $d < \epsilon \implies d' < \epsilon$. So $y \in B_d(x, \epsilon) \implies y \in B_{d'}(x, \epsilon)$.
Conversely, let $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$. Then $d' < \delta \implies d = \frac{d'}{1-d'} < \frac{\delta}{1-\delta} = \epsilon$. So $y \in B_{d'}(x,\delta) \implies y \in B_d(x,\epsilon)$.

**Edit 2:**
As pointed out by [Berci](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/41488/berci), this is the conclusion of the proof.
Finally, since the set of all open balls in a metric space form a basis for the space and $\forall x \in X, \forall \epsilon > 0$ we have that $B_d(x,\epsilon) \subseteq B_{d'}(x, \epsilon)$ and $B_{d'}(x, \delta) \subseteq B_{d}(x, \epsilon)$, $d$ and $d'$ induce the same topology on $X$.

Comment: What you have done is correct.

Comment: @Gae.S. why it is dreadful?

Comment: @808GroundState I think that the question is different: in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309198/if-dx-y-is-a-metric-then-fracdx-y1-dx-y-is-also-a-metric they're asking if $d/(1+d)$ is also a metric given a metric $d$; in my question I'm asking if the proof that $d$ and $d'$ are equivalent metrics is correct

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy ok, thank you!

Comment: It's correct. Can you finish the proof? Why do these imply that the induced topologies are the same?

Comment: There is a related question here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863127/show-that-for-every-metric-d-the-metrics-d-1d-and-min-1-d-are-equ

Comment: @Berci you're right: see my edit :)

Comment: @ECL yeah, i've read it. I think is misleading because the question is different, but i've seen that the procedure is similar