# Prove that every metric space $(X,d)$ admits a metric $d'$ equivalent to $d$ which makes $X$ bounded.

Tags: metric-spaces, solution-verification, examples-counterexamples, equivalent-metrics

**Exercise**

Prove that every metric space $(X,d)$ admits a metric $d'$ equivalent to $d$ which makes $X$ bounded.

**EDIT**

**Definition**

Let $X$ be a non-empty set. We say the metrics $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ defined over $X$ are equivalent iff for every $x\in X$ and every $r > 0$:

(a) exists $s > 0$ such that $\{y\in X : d_{1}(x,y) < s\} \subset \{y\in X : d_{2}(x,y) < r\}$,

(b) exists $t > 0$ such that $\{y\in X : d_{2}(x,y) < t\} \subset \{y\in X : d_{1}(x,y) < r\}$.

**My attempt**

Based on the suggestion of @TheoBendit, if we take $d'(x,y) = \min\{d(x,y),1\}$, one has that for every $x\in X$ and every $r > 0$ there exists $s = \min\{r,1\}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\{y\in X : d'(x,y) < s\} \subset \{y\in X : d(x,y) < r\}.
\end{align*}

But I fail to prove the converse.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $d' = \min\{d, 1\}$ should work.

Comment: It's equivalent in that they generate the same topology. It's not equivalent in the sense that $c_1 d' \le d \le c_2 d'$ for some $c_1, c_2 > 0$. Indeed, if $d$ is unbounded, then it is impossible to find a bounded $d'$ satisfying these conditions.

Comment: As it happens, your metric would work. (Proving this happens to be exercise $1.2.11$ in Kreyszig's *Introductory Functional Analysis* textbook, hence how I recalled it.) Though it feels like your definition of boundedness *might* be different? What do you mean by $d' \le d$? And what do you mean by "bounded" in a precise manner?

Comment: In the following question one other bounded metric is also mentioned: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863127/show-that-for-every-metric-d-the-metrics-d-1d-and-min-1-d-are-equ?rq=1 . 
With the notation of that question, you can check that $d_1(x,y) < 1$ for all $x,y \in X$.